# Convert DataFrame Column to Factors

Tags: r, dataframe, na

R, RStudio

---

How do I convert DataFrame column to Factors?

I wish 0 is "North", 1 is "South", 2 is "East" and 3 is "West".

```
directions <- data.frame(
                          state=c("New York","New Jersey","Deleware","Texax","Alaska"),
                          travel=c(0,0,3,2,1)
                        )

head(directions)
```

Outputs

```
       state travel
1   New York      0
2 New Jersey      0
3   Deleware      3
4      Texax      2
5     Alaska      1
```

I tried the following, but the entire `travel` column is `NA`

```
directions$travel <- factor(directions$travel,levels=c("North","South","East","West"))
head(directions)
```

Outputs

```
state travel
1   New York   <NA>
2 New Jersey   <NA>
3   Deleware   <NA>
4      Texax   <NA>
5     Alaska   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specify it in `labels`

```
factor(directions$travel,labels=c("North","South","East","West"))
#[1] North North West  East  South
#Levels: North South East West
```

If we need a custom grouping, then specify the `levels` as well

```
factor(directions$travel,levels = c(0, 1, 2, 3), 
         labels=c("North","South","East","West"))
```